# Problems with remote ssh access to mysql with Workbench MacOS

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mac-os-x, ssh

I am having problems connecting Workbench with Siteground.
All my connection settings are as instructed, however my question is do I have to open port 3306 on my Mac to connect to the Siteground server?

I keep getting this error:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 through SSH tunnel

Comment: Have you checked if you can establish a ssh tunnel with your credentials?

Comment: I have downloaded the private key from the server and setup this key in Workbench. How else can I check this?

Comment: test it so https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/mac/  when you have established thta it works, you enter this in ssh (priot you have ti xhange ti tco over ssh) and then there is a second inout box for mysql where you put port 3306 and your credentilas for mysql.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to open the port 3306 on your Mac. The connection goes through the SSH tunnel, which uses a different port (default port: 22). The MySQL port is relevant only on the remote end of the tunnel. Imaging you would sit on that end with MySQL Workbench and have to enter the MySQL server details. Address, port, username (perhaps with host part) etc. all have to be specified as seen from that remote end.

Comment: The SSH port in the remote mysql server is localhost:3306. So I thought the connection to the other end was through the port 3306 from my terminal to the remote server. Also I have noticed that mysql is installed in my root and Workbench is running for my user. Would this be an issue?

Comment: Is the server actually running on 3306? You should check this first. Then see if you can reach it through your SSH connection in the terminal. When you set up an SSH connection manually, you have to specify which port to use locally. Use this to attempt the connection to your server (tunnel goes from <local-port> to <3306>. You can of course use 3306 for the local port, but I wouldn't do that, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for all the support I gave up on ssh connection and did it over TCP IP